# How to have QML settings persistent for the application's lifetime

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to create warning dialog that has a "Do not prompt again" option. However, because it's part of a stack view the dialog gets destroyed regularly, and it's properties get destroyed too. How do I create settings that are persistent for the life of the application, but get reset back to a default value when the application gets started?

```
Item {
    Button {
        id: backButton
        text: "Go Back"

        // todo: Figure out how to set this just once at the start of the application
        property bool promptOnClick: true
        onClicked: promptOnClick ? cautionDialog.open() : stackView.pop()
    }

    Dialog {
        id: cautionDialog
        title: "Caution"

        standardButtons: StandardButton.Ok | StandardButton.Cancel

        onAccepted: {
            if (checkboxDisablePrompt.checked) {
                backButton.promptOnClick = false
            }
            stackView.pop()
        }

        Row {
            CheckBox {
                id: checkboxDisablePrompt
                checked: false
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }

            Label {
                text: "Do not prompt again"
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not just do a global variable ```property bool hasPrompted: false``` and use it to decide if it should prompt, and change it to true when it prompts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want property values in the dialog to persist for the duration of the application.

A good option would be to write these as properties in item. The you can bind the correct properties in dialog to the ones you just created in item. Whenever you want to edit the property, edit it in the item.

Whenever the dialog is created, it will use the current values of the properties in item that it is bound too.

Comment: I tried the above, and it didn't work. The main issue is that this whole item regularly gets created/deleted (including the Item) during the stackView pop() on line 8.

Comment: Is the code you pasted above the entire qml class? If not could you please include the whole class? If Item isn't the root component of your class, try the above solution but add the new property to the root component, instead of to item like I mentioned above